# JTable valuechanged then change cell color

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, valuechangelistener

I have here a `JTable` with two(2) columns. The right column is an editable one while the other is not.

So, what my problem is that whenever the user changed the value of a cell, that specific cell will changed its cell color.

I wanna do this because I want to let the user know that he/she made some changes in the table.

I found this somewhere and it somehow solved my problem but 1 thing that didn't come up with my expectation is that after changing the value and clicked another cell, the color changes back to its original color. I want to let it stay until it is saved.

```
@Override
public Component prepareEditor(TableCellEditor editor, int data, int columns) {
    Component c = super.prepareEditor(editor, data, columns);
    c.setBackground(Color.RED);
    return c;
}
```

Is it possible? If yes, please show some example.

UPDATE:

```
    String[] columnname = {"Student Name", "Grade"};

    Object[][] data = {};

    gradetable = new JTable(data, columnname){
        private Object[][] rowData;

        public boolean isCellEditable(int data, int columns){
            return columns == 1;
        }


        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer r, int data, int columns){
            final Component c = super.prepareRenderer(r, data, columns);

            if (data % 2 == 0){
                c.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            }
            else{
                c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }

            if (isCellSelected(data, columns)){
                c.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
            }                

            return c;
        }

        @Override
        public Component prepareEditor(TableCellEditor editor, int data, int columns) {
            Component c = super.prepareEditor(editor, data, columns);
            c.setBackground(Color.RED);
            return c;
        }
    };

    gradetable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, columnname));
    gradetable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension (350, 130));
    gradetable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    gradetable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    gradetable.setGridColor(new Color(128,128,128,128));
    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(gradetable);
    panel3.add(jsp);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tables use a `TableCellRenderer` to paint values on the screen.  The editors and renderers don't actually have anything to do with each other (from a painting point of view).

So once the editor has been dismissed (accepted or cancelled), the cell is repainted using the assigned `TableCellRenderer`

You need to supply, in your table model, some way to determine which rows have been updated and change the state of the renderer to match.

FYI- The `DefaultTableCellRenderer` uses a `JLabel` as it's base renderer, so it is transparent by default; you will need to make it opaque to make it render properly.

Check out [Using custom renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) for more details

**Update with example**

This is nothing more then a proof of concept.  It will not meet your absolute requirements and you should take a serious look at the tutorial linked above.

[image: Example image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class TableEdit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TableEdit();
    }

    public TableEdit() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
            table.setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke(true);
            TableColumnModel model = table.getColumnModel();
            model.getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new MyTableCellRenderer());
            add(new JScrollPane(table));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }
    }

    public class MyData {

        private String key;
        private String value;
        private boolean changed;

        public MyData(String key, String value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.changed = false;
        }

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String newValue) {
            if (value == null ? newValue != null : !value.equals(newValue)) {
                value = newValue;
                changed = true;
            }
        }

        public boolean hasChanged() {
            return changed;
        }
    }

    public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<MyData> data;

        public MyTableModel() {
            data = new ArrayList<>(25);
            for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
                data.add(new MyData("A" + (index + 1), "B" + (index + 1)));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            MyData myData = data.get(rowIndex);
            Object value = null;
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    value = myData.getKey();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    value = myData.getValue();
                    break;
            }
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return columnIndex == 1;
        }

        public boolean hasChanged(int rowIndex) {
            MyData myData = data.get(rowIndex);
            return myData.hasChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            MyData myData = data.get(rowIndex);
            myData.setValue(aValue == null ? null : aValue.toString());
        }
    }

    public class MyTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            setOpaque(isSelected);
            TableModel model = table.getModel();
            if (model instanceof MyTableModel) {
                MyTableModel myModel = (MyTableModel) model;
                if (myModel.hasChanged(row)) {
                    if (!isSelected) {
                        setBackground(Color.RED);
                        setOpaque(true);
                    } 
                }
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi MadProgrammer, thanks for the response. Can you show me a sample program that solves my problem?

Comment: Sure, its linked in the answer

Comment: Hi there MadProgrammer, I've studied your code but I don't know how to associate your code to my code. So, I edited my problem and posted the code that creates my jtable. I hope you can revise it so that it works the with what you did above. Thanks in advance.